# resolve macro variables for saving/naming a dataset in SAS

Tags: macros, sas, naming, resolve

I have problem saving a dataset using macro variables to a desired directory.

Basically, I want to save the dataset "_est" to library "sret" according to the values of &var and &age. I wrote the following code:

```
%let var=k;
%let age=2;
...
...
data sret.est_&var&age._b3; 
  set _est;
run;
```

What I want is a dataset named as "est_k2_b3.sas7bdat" in "sret". But what the code gives me is a dataset "est_k2.sas7bdat" saved in the folder I want and another dataset "_b3" in the working library. Both datasets are identical. I'm quite puzzled how to solve this.

Comment: This code looks right. Are you sure this data statement is exactly what you used? What operating system are you on?

Comment: The behavior you're getting suggests there's a space at the end of &age somehow. Are you changing it elsewhere? Try `%put "&age";` and look at the log to see if there's a space.

Comment: @itzy I'm using Windows 7 and SAS9.3.

Comment: Actually I had it successfully worked out once before. But couldn't get it now. I don't know if it's got anything to do with the macros I'm using. I have a main macro that calls other .sas files as sub-routines and the codes are in the subroutines.

Comment: Previously, I also encountered similar problems when I wanted to directly include codes like this in a macro.

Comment: @itzy I see. Maybe it gets a space somehow in between the codes. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As itzy pointed out you have a space after "2" that splits your dataset name in two.

I can replicate the issue only defining the macro variable `age` with a call symput:

```
data _null_;
    age='2 ';
    call symput('age',age);
run;
```

If this is the case you can solve it by removing the space in the data step with a `strip()`, using a `call symputx()` (to be used with numbers) or re-declaring your variable after the data step with a `%let`, that automatically removes spaces:

```
%let age= &age.;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't get values for &age from datasets. I just manually set its value. Btw, how to use `call symputx()`?

Comment: Use it instead of `call symput()` in a data step. If you define the `age` variable manually or outside a data step then remove spaces with the `%let age= &age.;` statement before you use it to construct a dataset name (as in your example).

Answer (score 0):

Had a very similar problem. Somehow a space is added until you use strip(). Here's the example below.

```
data test;
    input numdays;
    datalines;
    31
;

%macro monthly(months);

%let count=%sysfunc(countw(&months.));
%do i=1 %to &count.;
    %let value=%qscan(&months.,&i,%str(,));
    %let month=%sysfunc(strip(&value.));
    %put &value.;
    %put &month.;

data value_&value.;
    set test;
run;

data month_&month.;
    set test;
run;

%end;
%mend;
%monthly(%str(oct,jan));
```

Comment: If you don't quote the spaces by using `%QSCAN()` instead of `%SCAN()` then there is no need to later remove them.

Comment: Why are you using comma as the delimiter in the first place?  Why not use a space?  Or at least some other character than a comma.  It will make the macro call much easier.